# Why doesn't Firebase Console create anonymous user when sign in anonymously under Android onCreate?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

First of all, I've implemented Firebase authentication anonymous sign in without an issue when there's a sign in button. But when I put the sign in code under `onCreate()` to simulate automatic sign in, it does show sign in anonymously success and I'm able to read and write but the Console doesn't create the user. Why is it? Here's my code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val config = AndroidApplicationConfiguration()
    initialize(Main(this), config)

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    mAuth.signInAnonymously()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:success")
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Authentication succeeded.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    /* Assign 'user' */
                    user = mAuth.currentUser

                    // Write a message to the database
                    val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    val uidPath: String? = user?.uid

                    val uidRef = database.getReference("users")
                    val nameRef = database.getReference("users/$uidPath/name")
                    val emailRef = database.getReference("users/$uidPath/email")
                    val authProviderRef = database.getReference("users/$uidPath/authProvider")

                    uidRef.setValue("${user?.uid}")
                    nameRef.setValue("${user?.displayName}")
                    emailRef.setValue("${user?.email}")
                    user?.providerData?.forEach {
                        authProviderRef.setValue(it.providerId)
                    }
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInAnonymously:failure", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            }
}
```

[image: Auth]

[image: database]

Comment: So you are basically saying that the anonymous authentication is successful but you cannot see the user in your Firebase Console / Authentication section?

Comment: Yes, it even shows the uid I sent to Database, but nothing in Authentication section.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the correct project?

Comment: Yes. I only have 1 project on there, and I've tested it multiple times with the same result. As I mentioned It works as intended when there's a sign in button that I click on, Without it, the console doesn't create the user for me.

Comment: Can please you add a screenshot from your console?

Comment: I added the screenshots to my question above.

Comment: Have you enabled anonymous authentication in your Firebase Console?

Comment: Yes. I enabled it when i test with sign in button

Comment: task.getException() print anything?

Comment: It doesn't print anything.

Comment: So you say that this message is printed `signInAnonymously:success`, right?

Comment: Yes. Everything in the listener is success except for the console don't create user.

Comment: I see, I'll write you an answer right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that before I tried this automatic sign in, the user (firebaseAuth.currentUser) already exists. So when I sign out explicitly using FirebaseAuth.getInstance.signOut() this way the user becomes null and firebase will create a user.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you aren't writing the `email` and `name` in your database, isn't an issue because when you are trying to authenticate an user anonymous, the `FirebaseUser` object does not contain any values for those properties. So this is the reason why those properties are empty in your database. If you want to have them populated, you should link the anonymous account with a real account as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account).

The reason that you get no user added in your Firebase Console is because you aren't passing to the Task's [addOnCompleteListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#addOnCompleteListener(android.app.Activity,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener%3CTResult%3E)) method an activity and and a `OnCompleteListener` object you are only passing `this`, which is not correct. To solve this, please use the following code:

```
firebaseAuth!!.signInAnonymously()
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:success")
                Toast.makeText(this, "Authentication succeeded.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                /* Assign 'user' */
                user = firebaseAuth!!.currentUser

                // Write a message to the database
                val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                val uidPath: String? = user?.uid

                val uidRef = database.getReference("users")
                val nameRef = database.getReference("users/$uidPath/name")
                val emailRef = database.getReference("users/$uidPath/email")
                val authProviderRef = database.getReference("users/$uidPath/authProvider")

                uidRef.setValue("${user?.uid}")
                nameRef.setValue("${user?.displayName}")
                emailRef.setValue("${user?.email}")
                user?.providerData?.forEach {
                    authProviderRef.setValue(it.providerId)
                }
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "signInAnonymously:failure", task.exception)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Though this is not exactly the solution as the onComepleteListener object is redundant, I indirectly found the reason why Firebase wasn't creating user. The reason is that before I tried this automatic sign in, the user (firebaseAuth.currentUser) already exists. So when I sign out explicitly using FirebaseAuth.getInstance.signOut() this way the user becomes null and firebase will create another for me. Up voted though :)